# iPhone SDK UIImagePicker Hide Controls

Tags: ios4, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I know how to hide the camera controls (.showsCameraControls = NO) but if I do this I will lose the button to switch from rear to front facing camera which I need, is there a way to keep that but lose the controls at the bottom?

I tried keeping all of the controls and overlaying on top of the bottom bar but the bottom bar is always on top of the cameraOverlayView whatever I try. I think it used to work but doesn't in 5.0.

I also realise you can add your own button to switch between the 2 cameras (.cameraDevice) but I want to keep it looking as much like the proper interface as possible.

Any pointers are really appreciated, The whole point of this is that I need to call .takePicture myself but want the interface to look exactly like it normally does with all of the default buttons.